# JQuery slider save value after submit and change div width/height

Tags: php, jquery

I want to adjust the width and height of a div with a slider. Once I click the submit button, I want the width and height of my div adjusted to the value I set the slider to. What I achieved so far is the div adjusting as I slide back and forth, but once I click submit, it resets to normal rather than displaying the same size it was left on.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({
      value:parseInt($("input[name='slider_id']").val(), 10), min: 10, max: 400, step: 10, slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val(ui.value);
        $('.ad_display').css('width', (ui.value+50) + 'px');
        $('.ad_display').css('height', (ui.value+50) + 'px');
      }
    });
    $("#amount").val($("#slider").slider("value"));
  });
</script>
```

the slider:

```
<input type="text" id="amount" class="slider_size" name="slider_id" value="<?php echo $ad_size; ?>"> %<br><div id="slider"></div>
```

How do I get the value to be the width and height?

I tried getting the value with php with isset($_GET['slider_id']) but that didn't work

```
  echo  '<div class="ad_display" id="'.$date.'" style="width:'.$ad_size.'+50px;height:'.$ad_size.'+50px;">blabla</div>'
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: My php is way rusty so I won't post code/an answer, but generally, you can declare a hidden input field and store the value in there from the JS function. Then after the post back, use $_GET[] with the name of the hidden input, with a fallback to your default value.

Comment: the value stays what it was set to but the width and height goes back to original for some reason.. and why do i need a hidden field?

Comment: A hidden field will post whatever value back to the server, and will be available to your php code. Then you can reuse that value to set the width and height from the stored value of the hidden field. The issue you're experiencing is due to the stateless nature of web architecture. A hidden field is just part of the form data, and is one way of maintaining state between requests.

Comment: I am hoping that you didn't use echo isset($_GET['slider_id']).  Isset only determines whether or not the given variable has a value(e.g. it returns TRUE or FALSE... otherwise known as a boolean value).  Can we see the rest of your code?